# How to fix a pull request branch that suffered a bad merge?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

I have a pull request branch that includes only say 15 commits and after a bad merge (or a bad rebase), commits that have already been merged into master are showing up on GitHub as new commits.

It's likely that these commits were created when a third-party branch was merged into the pull request branch before that third-party branch was merged into master.

Regardless I need to clean this pull request branch in order to have GitHub only display in the commit and file diffs the 15 commits that are specific to the pull request branch itself.

Do you have any tips and tricks to achieve this? In the past I've simply cherry picked the commits I knew were exclusive to the pull request branch into a new branch. Then I deleted the original pull request branch, renamed the new branch with the same name as the original pull request branch and force pushed that branch to GitHub, resulting in a clean diff.

However this technique isn't ideal on long running branches with many collaborators because due to merges along the lifespan of the original pull request branch it's tricky to figure out which commits are exclusive to the branch.

Comment: Can you show the current state of the repo using `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` ?

Answer (score 1):

[Rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) removes merge commits as part of the process.

That's probably your best bet to clean this up - rebase the pull request branch onto master.

I would suggest creating a throwaway branch to test the rebase with though.

- `git checkout pull-request-branch`
- `git checkout -b rebase-test`
- `git rebase master rebase-test`

That would give you the option to diff the resulting `rebase-test` branch against master and the `pull-request-branch` to ensure you've got the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to remove several commits on a branch, I use interactive rebase

```
rebase -i <SHA of the last commit onto you rebase>
```

then you can just comment the commits (or remove the lines) that you want to not replay.

If you need to find commits common to two branches you can use `git show-branch`.

Aside note, interactive rebase is very usefull with `git reset` when you need to split a branch in several ones with exclusive subsets of commits.